# is possible to fit this csv file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

i try to build model this model will detect if the car drifting or normal or static so in the beginning, I collection some video from the internet after that I use this repository from GitHub `Deep-SORT-YOLOv4` this link `https://github.com/LeonLok/Deep-SORT-YOLOv4` to find the boundary box for each car and converted the x and y center to CSV and do it for some video, in the end, i collect all CSV file and compile to one file and this photo how the CSV file looks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apDBm.png)

the reason to do like this someone recommended me this way
so after that, I try to do a convolutional neural network
so I start the write the code and when i start to fit the model
I face this error

> Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

my question now is I find this error because the format CSV file and I can fit the model with this format or not  and how can fix this error

this my code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/centersofallcars.csv')
y = df['Activity']
x = df.drop(['Trajectory', 'Activity' , 'x THEN y' , 'id' ,'video' ] , axis=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
def create_cnn_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
    
    return model

model = create_cnn_model()
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-4, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=opt, 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
BATCH_SIZE=64
EPOCHS=100
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
          epochs=EPOCHS, 
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test)
         )
```

also is i miss something should do it before I start to fit the model

Comment: Convert numpy array to tensor before fit to the model use `x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')`. Other fault may data preprocessing. Verify everything is properly formatted such as categoricals, nans, strings. Thanks!